# Rotating the y-axis label

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, yaxis

I am trying to rotate the title of the Y axis so it is horizontal.  I do not want the tick labels horizontal just the title of the Y axis.  I have to use subplots as I am making multiple plots at once.  Here is the below script in which I have tried to rotate the Y axis title.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_title(r'$\alpha$ > \beta_i$', fontsize=20)
ax.set(xlabel='meters $10^1$', ylabel=r'Hertz $(\frac{1}{s})$')
ax.set(xlabel=r's(t) = \mathcal(A)\/\sin(2 \omega t)', ylabel=r'Hertz $(\frac{1}{s})$')
ax.set(ylabel="North $\uparrow$",fontsize=9,rotate=90)
plt.show()
```

When I run it I get an error:

> TypeError: There is no AxesSubplot property "rotate"

How can I tweak this program so that the Y axis is rotating horizontally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using `ax.set` you are attempting to set properties of the `axes` rather than properties of the `ylabel` text object.

Rather than using `ax.set` you can instead use `xlabel` and `ylabel` to create the x and y labels and pass in kwargs to modify their appearance. Also the property name is `rotation` rather than `rotate`. Also you'll want to set the `rotation` to `0` as the default is `90` which is why it's rotated in the first place.

```
plt.title(r'$\alpha > \beta_i$', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel(r'meters $10^1$', fontsize=9)
plt.ylabel("North $\uparrow$", fontsize=9, rotation=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42100250/7758804) works, it requires switching from the [explicit Axes interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface), to the [implicit pyplot interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-implicit-pyplot-interface), which [shouldn't be done](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#why-be-explicit).

[`set_ylabel()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html)

> **kwargs [`Text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) properties: Text properties control the appearance of the label.

[`matplotlib.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)

> [`position`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_position)   Set the (x, y) position of the text. `xy`: `(float, float)`

> [`rotation`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_rotation)   Set the rotation of the text. `s`: `float or {'vertical', 'horizontal'}`. The rotation angle in degrees in mathematically positive direction (counterclockwise). 'horizontal' equals 0, 'vertical' equals 90.

> [`rotation_mode`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_rotation_mode) Set text rotation mode. `m`: `{None, 'default', 'anchor'}`. If `None` or `'default'`, the text will be first rotated, then aligned according to their horizontal and vertical alignments. If `'anchor'`, then alignment occurs before rotation.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_title(r'$\alpha > \beta_i$', fontsize=20)
ax.set(xlabel='meters $10^1$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$North \uparrow$', fontsize=9, rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]