# Rotate axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot, axis-labels

I have a plot that looks like this (this is the famous Wine dataset):

[image]

As you can see, the x-axis labels overlap and thus I need to be rotated.

**NB!** I am not interested in rotating the x-ticks (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37708190/9035706)), but the label text, i.e. `alcohol`, `malic_acid`, etc.

The logic of creating the plot is the following: I create a grid using `axd = fig.subplot_mosaic(...)` and then for the bottom plots I set the labels with `axd[...].set_xlabel("something")`. Would be great if `set_xlabel` would take a `rotation` parameter, but unfortunately that is not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html) `set_xlabel` accepts [text arguments](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text), of which `rotation` is one.

The example I used to test this is shown below, though .

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot()
plt.gca().set_xlabel('Test', rotation='vertical')
```

Answer (score 2):

- While the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72282427/7758804) works, it treats the subplots as if the [implicit pyplot interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-implicit-pyplot-interface) is being used, while the [explicit Axes interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface) is actually being used. When working with subplots, it is always better [to be explicit](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#why-be-explicit). Additionally, `plt.gca()` only gets the last `axes`.
- [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `subplots=True`, and [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) with `nrows` and / or `ncols` greater than 1, returns a `numpy.ndarray` of `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes`.

  - [How to fix 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure' when plotting subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64230180/7758804)
  - The easiest way to work with the `axes` array, is to flatten it with `.flat`, `.flatten`, or `.ravel`.

    - [What is the difference between flatten and ravel functions in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28930465/7758804)
    - [numpy difference between flat and ravel()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38357811/7758804)
- There are several ways to interact with an individual `Axes`.

  1. Iterate through all of them: `for ax in axes.flat:`
  2. Iterate through a slice of them: `for ax in axes.flat[-4:]:` for the last four.
  3. Select a specific `Axes` to work on after `axes = axes.flat`: `ax[4]`, `ax[-1]`, etc.
- [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html) is used to rotate the axis label.

  - Accepts properties from [`matplotlib.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html) as `**kwargs`.
  - Also see [Rotating the y-axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76434532/7758804)
  - [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html) can be used to set the various ylabel parameters.

### Imports and Sample DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# sinusoidal sample data
sample_length = range(1, 16+1)
rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
data = np.array([np.sin(t*rads) for t in sample_length])

# create a wide dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, index=pd.Series(rads.tolist(), name='radians'), columns=[f'freq: {i}x' for i in sample_length])

# transform df to a long form
dfl = df.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index()
```

### `pandas.DataFrame.plot` with `subplots=True`

```py
axes = df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(4, 4), figsize=(10, 10), color='tab:purple', legend=False)

# flatten the axes array
axes = axes.flatten()

# iterate through each axes and associated column
for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    
    # set the axes title
    ax.set_title(col)
    
    # extract the existing xaxis label
    xlabel = ax.get_xlabel()
    
    # set the xaxis label with rotation
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, rotation='vertical')
```

[image]

### `plt.subplots`

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(10, 10), sharex=True, tight_layout=True)

axes = axes.flat

for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):

    df.plot(y=col, ax=ax, title=col, legend=False)
    xlabel = ax.get_xlabel()
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, rotation='vertical')
```

[image]

### [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html)

- `relplot` is a [figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions), which returns a [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), from which the subplots are extracted with `axes = g.axes`.

```py
g = sns.relplot(data=dfl, kind='line', x='radians', y='value', col='variable', col_wrap=4, height=2.3)

axes = g.axes.ravel()

for ax in axes[-4:]:
    xlabel = ax.get_xlabel()
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, rotation='vertical')
```

[image]

---

### DataFrmames

#### `df.head()`

```
         freq: 1x  freq: 2x  freq: 3x  freq: 4x  freq: 5x  freq: 6x  freq: 7x  freq: 8x  freq: 9x  freq: 10x  freq: 11x  freq: 12x  freq: 13x  freq: 14x  freq: 15x  freq: 16x
radians                                                                                                                                                                       
0.00     0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
0.01     0.010000  0.019999  0.029996  0.039989  0.049979  0.059964  0.069943  0.079915  0.089879   0.099833   0.109778   0.119712   0.129634   0.139543   0.149438   0.159318
0.02     0.019999  0.039989  0.059964  0.079915  0.099833  0.119712  0.139543  0.159318  0.179030   0.198669   0.218230   0.237703   0.257081   0.276356   0.295520   0.314567
0.03     0.029996  0.059964  0.089879  0.119712  0.149438  0.179030  0.208460  0.237703  0.266731   0.295520   0.324043   0.352274   0.380188   0.407760   0.434966   0.461779
0.04     0.039989  0.079915  0.119712  0.159318  0.198669  0.237703  0.276356  0.314567  0.352274   0.389418   0.425939   0.461779   0.496880   0.531186   0.564642   0.597195
```

#### `dfl.head()`

```
   radians  variable     value
0     0.00  freq: 1x  0.000000
1     0.01  freq: 1x  0.010000
2     0.02  freq: 1x  0.019999
3     0.03  freq: 1x  0.029996
4     0.04  freq: 1x  0.039989
```